# How to tell whether a virtual desktop already exists

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm using the VirtualDesktop module in Windows Powershell. Trying to test whether a virtual desktop already exists, and if not add it. My code, however, always fails to identify whether the virtual desktop already exists.

```
$DesktopList = Get-DesktopList

# $DesktopList returns:

Number Name      Visible
------ ----      -------
     0 Desktop 1   False
     1 Web          True
     2 Explore     False
     3 Mail        False
     4 MSO         False
```

I've tried

```
If (-Not $DesktopList -Contains 'Web') # ---> returns False (should be True)
If ($DesktopList -Contains 'Web' -eq $FALSE) # ---> returns True (should be False)
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with the index vs name (i.e., "Web") being referenced, but I'm not clear how to fix.

Thank you.

Comment: You just need to reference the `Name` property of the object. `$desktopList.Name -contains 'Web'`.

Comment: that is not a standard cmdlet. is it from >>> PowerShell Gallery | VirtualDesktop 1.4.1 — https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/VirtualDesktop/1.4.1 <<< if so, you likely otta add that info to your Question.

Comment: Thank you both. Yes, PowerShell Gallery | VirtualDesktop 1.4.1.
Santiago:
'''
$DesktopList = Get-DesktopList
$DesktopList.name -Contains 'Web'
'''
returns an error:  "
Get-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'.

I also tried:
'''
$DesktopList = Get-DesktopList.name
'''
but that also throws an error: The term 'Get-DesktopList.name' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, ...

Comment: The following runs without error, but also returns "false"!
'''

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $DesktopList = Get-Desktoplist - name

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $DesktopList

Number Name    Visible
------ ----    -------
     0 primary    True
     1 Web       False



PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $DesktopList -Contains 'Web'
False
'''

Comment: FYI, both of the following return the same set of values for $Desktoplist
'''
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $DesktopList = Get-Desktoplist -name
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $DesktopList = Get-Desktoplist
'''
Number    Name    Visible
------        ------     -------
     0          primary    True
     1          Web       False
'''
In both cases, 
'''
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $DesktopList -Contains 'Web'
'''
returns: false

Answer (score 0):

It seems VirtualDesktop doesn't support the -name parameter (or at least I couldn't figure out how to make it work). Instead, I used the brute-force approach of first deleting all virtual desktops, then re-adding them one at a time, and (if not already running) launching applicable apps on each virtual desktop.